# Can you join edges when they go to the same node?

Tags: graphviz, dot

See the line on the leftmost side of this image.

[image]

This isn't a perfect example because the lines don't end on a node, but imagine that there is a node on the bottom left corner of the image. Normally in graphviz if I have a graph like this:

```
digraph G {
    a->c
    b->c
}
```

Then I get two separate lines going into `c`. Is it possible to have these two lines join before they reach `c`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have two lines join before they reach `c` but, as far as I can see, it requires inserting an invisible node to do it. e.g.:

```
digraph G {
    x [style=invis, height=0, label=""]
    a->x [dir=none]
    b->x [dir=none]
    x->c
}
```

... which gives:

[image]